# Pyspark counting the occurance of values with keys

Tags: pyspark

I have a list of `(key,value)` pairs of the form:

```
x=[(('cat','dog),('a','b')),(('cat','dog'),('a','b')),(('mouse','rat'),('e','f'))]
```

I want to count the number of times each value tuple appears with the key tuple.

Desired output:

```
[(('cat','dog'),('a','b',2)),(('mouse','rat'),('e','f',1))]
```

A working solution is:

```
xs=sc.parallelize(x)
xs=xs.groupByKey()
xs=xs.map(lambda (x,y):(x,Counter(y))
```

however for large datasets, this method fills up the disk space (~600GB). I was trying to implement a similar solution using `reduceByKey`:

```
xs=xs.reduceByKey(Counter).collect()
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Also, FYI, you should never use `groupByKey` if you can avoid it. Databricks wrote why [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I usually do it:

```
xs=sc.parallelize(x)
a = xs.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
```

`a.collect()` yields:

```
[((('mouse', 'rat'), ('e', 'f')), 1), ((('cat', 'dog'), ('a', 'b')), 2)]
```

I'm going to assume that you want the counts (here, 1 and 2) inside the second key in the (key1, key2) pair.

To achieve that, try this:

```
a.map(lambda x: (x[0][0], x[0][1] + (x[1],))).collect()
```

The last step basically remaps it so that you get the first key pair (like `('mouse','rat')`), then takes the second key pair (like `('e','f')`), and then adds the `tuple` version of `b[1]`, which is the count, to the second key pair.